# Can I render multiple HTML, then serve them inside a zip file?

Tags: python, django, django-views, zip

I have a site that takes orders of questions for schools.
These orders have some questions, and these questions are outputted as HTML.
When the order is complete I want the user to download these HTML inside a ZIP file, along other files (a PDF containing order details, and two other PDF that renders these question as a school exam)

I can easily render the other files using WeasyPrint, but I can't find a way to render this multiple HTML.

The code for the view:

```
    
def complete_order_zip_view(request, pk):
    html_list = list()
    order = pk
    zipfile_name = f'encomenda_{order}.zip'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    template_name = "single_question.html"
    questions = Question.objects.filter(Q(question_order=order) & Q(revision_approval=True))
    
    for question in questions:
        rendered_question = render(request, template_name, content_type="application/zip")
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        html_list.append(buffer)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile_name, 'w') as zipMe:        
        for html in html_list:
            zipMe.write(str(html), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={zipfile_name}'

    return response
```

I tried to append directly the rendered question also, but it gave me an error stating that Question object had no attribute "META"

Comment: It needs to be HTML, since it's the way all the schools involved save the questions.

Comment: And the zip is also needed because I need to provide each question as a separate file.

Comment: @K J I updated the question with my view